# compare columns then add text after last line

Tags: excel, vba

so i am trying to compare g1:g51 on one worksheet to m11:m15 if match found then go  to skip next blank in "M" and insert next text that is in "G" it keeps erroring at wsDest.Range("M") = inmatch2. What am i doing wrong?

```
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
    Dim wsCopy3 As Worksheet
    Dim i2 As Integer
    Dim inrow2 As Integer
    Dim inmatch2 As String
    Dim k2 As Integer
    Dim outrow2 As Integer
    Dim outmatch2 As String


'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
    Set wsCopy = Worksheets("Sheet1")   
    Set wsCopy3 = Worksheets("Sheet3")

    If wsCopy3.Range("b1") > 0 Then     

    inrow2 = 10     
        For i2 = 1 To inrow2
            inmatch2 = wsCopy.Range("a" & i2)

        If inmatch2 = "" Then Exit For

    outrow2 = 25
        For k2 = 1 To outrow2
            outmatch2 = wsCopy3.Range("b" & k2)

            If outmatch2 = inmatch2 Then
                Exit For
            End If

           If outmatch2 = "" Then
                wsCopy3.Range("b" & k2) = inmatch2
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

            If outmatch2 = "" Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: which row in M?  you named the column but not the row.

Comment: And it should also error on `"m & k2"` as the `& k2` is in the quotes and it should be outside.

Comment: scott it did error out on that i just fixed that. the first row after the first blank in column m but i dont know how to tell it that? pretty new here to vba sorry.

Comment: As Scott said, you named the column "M" , but not the row in the following Code: `wsDest.Range("M") = inmatch2`. This occurs twice in your code. once on the 9th line from the last `end if` and the 4th line from the last `end if` statement.  I'm guessing you want something like `wsDest.Range("M" & k2) = inmatch2`

Comment: guys kept playing with the coding and i have gotten it work.  i ediited the above post to what i finally got to work.

Answer (score 0):

Sub ADDING()
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
      Dim wsCopy3 As Worksheet
    Dim i2 As Integer
    Dim inrow2 As Integer
    Dim inmatch2 As String
    Dim k2 As Integer
    Dim outrow2 As Integer
    Dim outmatch2 As String

```
'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
Set wsCopy = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set wsCopy3 = Worksheets("Sheet3")


If wsCopy3.Range("b1") > 0 Then


    inrow2 = 10


    For i2 = 1 To inrow2
        inmatch2 = wsCopy.Range("a" & i2)
        If inmatch2 = "" Then Exit For

        outrow2 = 25
        For k2 = 1 To outrow2
            outmatch2 = wsCopy3.Range("b" & k2)
            If outmatch2 = inmatch2 Then
            Exit For
            End If

            If outmatch2 = "" Then
            wsCopy3.Range("b" & k2) = inmatch2
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If outmatch2 = "" Then
                Exit For
        End If
    Next

End If
```

End Sub